# git error: failed to push some refs to remote

Tags: git, github

I can't push now, though I could do it yesterday.

When I use `git push origin master`, I get an error:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/REDACTED.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/REDACTED.git (push)

$ git push origin master
Username for 'https://github.com': REDACTED
Password for 'https://REDACTED@github.com':
To https://github.com/REDACTED.git
! [rejected]         master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/REDACTED.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

What my working directory and remote repository looks like:

[image: Screenshot of Windows file folder with these directories: .git, css, js. And these files: index.php, readme, setsu.php. The word "local" with an arrow points to the css-folder. Below, screenshot with heading "github", and a css-folder and index.php-file]

Comment: looks like your local repo is not in sync with the git repo. did you try to do git pull ?

Comment: yes, but I have no idea with the following syntax after git pull it says git pull <remote> <branch>, can you let me see an example syntax for git pull?

Comment: Do check this similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18588974/git-prevents-pushing-after-amending-a-commit

Comment: @R11G thank you sir! this link helped me http://stackoverflow.com/a/18589043/3626672

Comment: I got that error on a new repo. This helped: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6518774/2067690

Comment: Kindly check if you are in `master` branch then run `git checkout -b main` and then `git push origin main`

Comment: hey, if you find this on Google at this time, check if GitHub is down -> https://www.githubstatus.com/

Comment: for me, I had to add and commit

Comment: Here is Step By Step Solution >> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114676/git-error-failed-to-push-some-refs-to-remote/70585050#70585050

Comment: Definitely check githubstatus.com ! Start there.

Comment: Related: *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way***, *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface.*).

Comment: Check if your `branch name` is the same in the local and remote repo.

You might have named your main branch `master` in the remote repo and `Main` in the local repo.

Answer (score 1279, accepted):

(Note: [starting Oct. 2020](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-08-26-set-the-default-branch-for-newly-created-repositories/), any new repository is created with the default branch `main`, not `master`. And you can [rename existing repository default branch from `master` to `main`](https://github.com/github/renaming).
The rest of this 2014 answer has been updated to use "`main`")

(The following assumes `github.com` itself is *not* down, as [eri0o](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965638/eri0o) points out in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114676/git-error-failed-to-push-some-refs-to-remote/24114760#comment121465079_24114676): see [`www.githubstatus.com`](https://www.githubstatus.com/) to be sure)

If the GitHub repo has seen new commits pushed to it, while you were working locally, I would advise using:

```
git pull --rebase
git push
```

The full syntax is:

```
git pull --rebase origin main
git push origin main
```

[With Git 2.6+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30209750/6309) (Sept. 2015), after having done (once)

```
git config --global pull.rebase true
git config --global rebase.autoStash true
```

A simple `git pull` would be enough.
(Note: with [Git 2.27 Q2 2020](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61562652/6309), a `merge.autostash` is also available for your regular pull, without rebase)

That way, you would replay (the `--rebase` part) your local commits on top of the newly updated `origin/main` (or `origin/yourBranch`: `git pull origin yourBranch`).

See a more complete example in the [chapter 6 Pull with rebase](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000561/ch06.html#pull-rebase) of the [Git Pocket Book](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000561).

I would recommend a:

```
# add and commit first
#
git push -u origin main

# Or git 2.37 Q2 2022+
git config --global push.autoSetupRemote true
git push
```

That would establish a tracking relationship between your local main branch and its upstream branch.
After that, any future push for that branch can be done with a simple:

```
git push
```

Again, with [Git 2.37+ and its global option `push.autoSetupRemote`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72401899/6309), a simple `git push` even for the first one would do the same (I.e: establishing a tracking relationship between your local `main` branch and its upstream branch `origin/main`).

See "[Why do I need to explicitly push a new branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/6309)".

---

Since the OP already [reset and redone its commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18589043/6309) on top of `origin/main`:

```
git reset --mixed origin/main
git add .
git commit -m "This is a new commit for what I originally planned to be amended"
git push origin main
```

There is no need to `pull --rebase`.

Note: `git reset --mixed origin/main` can also be written `git reset origin/main`, since the `--mixed` option is the default one when using [`git reset`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset).

Comment: is it OK to execute your suggested git pull --rebase...? coz I already done > git reset --mixed origin/master
> git add .
> git commit -m "This is a new commit for what I originally planned to be an amendmend"
> git push origin master suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18588974/git-prevents-pushing-after-amending-a-commit/18589043#18589043 btw your answer looks helpful sir

Comment: For me, I just needed to run "git commit".  :(

Comment: Thanks, fixed a stupid issue with Git LFS, I've surrendered myself to having to use the command line from now on as a result haha.

Comment: In my case, I can push using Github Desktop Application but I can't in IntellijIdea. I got the same error as mentioned by OP in IntellijIdea SVN. I'm not sure if this is related to the local repo.

Comment: @MaXi32 Thenj it is best to ask a new question, with full details (OS, version of IntelliJ, Git, GitHub Desktop, URL,...)

Comment: Really super.. below commands worked for me...
git reset --mixed origin/master
git add .
git commit -m "This is a new commit for what I originally planned to be amended"
git push origin master

Thank you @VonC

Comment: Turns out github had problems.

Comment: @DavidJ Yes: https://twitter.com/coreyhaines/status/1153335824563539968 and https://twitter.com/JustinBeckwith/status/1153333169011118080

Comment: I also needed to do `git prune` in before pushing.

Comment: Warning, this will delete any existing local files. Before doing it take a copy of your local folder that contains your project files.

Comment: My whole project crashed, nice one

Comment: @James666 I am sorry to hear that. To avoid others having the same issue, what part of this answer was problematic in your case?

Comment: it happens when you don't specify branch name before pushing upto repo, simply use "git branch -M main" & it should work

Comment: @TylerC same here... wonder howd that happen.  Ive done it countless times.. perhaps the commit wasnt registered the first time it was entered...

Answer (score 257):

Try:

```
git push -f origin master
```

That should solve the problem.

Based on @Mehdi‘s comment, a clarification about `—force pushing`: The Git command above works safely only for the first commit. If there were already commits, pull requests or branches in previous, this resets all of it and set it from zero. If so, please refer @VonC‘s detailed answer for a better solution.

Comment: Works but bad, please don't use it unless you know what you're doing. (probably you don't know what you're doing if you're looking in S.O)

Comment: If you're going to try `-f`/`--force` it's always safer to use `--force-with-lease` instead, which will abort if there are downstream changes that would get clobbered by the push.  `--force-with-lease` is required for lots of everyday rebasing situations, but `--force` should almost never be needed.

Comment: I don't recommend it.

Comment: this one worked for me on Nginx Producntion Environment.

Answer (score 151):

If you just used `git init` and have added your files with `git add .` or something similar and have added your remote branch it might be that you just haven't committed (`git commit -m 'commit message'`) anything locally to push to the remote... I just had this error and that was my issue.

Comment: just ran into this. Commit command didn't work during the git add. good call. Thanks

Comment: Thanks man! That's it. I thought I committed my changes. Now git push -u origin master works fine.

Comment: On my case, the commit failed because I haven't added my credentials yet on a fresh install. Running the commit command again after adding my credentials fixed my issue

Answer (score 77):

I had the same problem. I was getting this problem because I had not made any commits, not even an initial commit and still I was trying to push.

Once I did `git commit -m "your msg"`, everything worked fine.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. The original question is about the **local** git being **behind**. In no way "being behind" can be resolved my making a local commit!

Comment: Oh I also forget to commit :p

Comment: This is also possible it won't allow you to push with an empty commit

Comment: An initial commit fixed it.

Comment: In my case, I had cherry-picked something onto my new branch and then tried to push, but got the error described in the new question; I needed to also add an "original" commit to the branch before I was able to push successfully.

Comment: I just had this problem and I forgot to commit. Error message should be more clear

Comment: Why people are upvoting this answer :P This answer does not apply to question asked.

Comment: It does apply to me since I was getting that exact error message and this solution fixed my problem.

Comment: Strange.. I did what you just suggested.. I had nothing to commit. But it worked. Just before I tried to commit again I did amend for changing last commit message.. don't really know if it relates..

Comment: I have done all things properly but getting an error after sowing your message I typed git status and it shows no commit. so I go through your process and was finally done.

Answer (score 66):

It has worked for me with this combination of several command lines:

```
git reset 
git remote -v
git pull --rebase
git init
git add -A
git commit -m "Add your commit"
git branch -M main
git push origin main --force
```

Be careful. If they have a Readme file, the `git reset` deletes them.

Comment: This sounds like dangerous advice. All implications and caveats ought to be explained in the answer.

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? What is it supposed to do? What are all the risks? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69852137/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: thi s was the right one

Answer (score 49):

Rename your branch and then push, e.g.:

```
git branch -m new-name
git push -u new-name
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Wow, this actually worked, but why? I had a hyphen in my local branch name: `my-branch_wont_push`. Once I renamed it to `my_branch_wont_push`, then `git push -u origin my_branch_wont_push` worked for me.

Comment: Thanks. As @cdabel mentioned, the hyphen was the culprit. Changed it to underscore and my push went through.

Comment: I simply renamed my branch to something else (which contained a hyphen) and it also worked. Don't know why though.

Answer (score 37):

1. `git init`
2. `git remote add origin https://gitlab.com/crew-chief-systems/bot`
3. `git remote -v` (for checking current repository)
4. `git add -A`(add all files)
5. `git commit -m 'Added my project'`
6. `git pull --rebase origin master`
7. `git push  origin master`

Comment: before pushing the code you need to pull from repository

Comment: you can simply write like git pull  --rebase origin master

Comment: This worked for me, had a refs issue, which this fixed.

Comment: error: cannot spawn sh: No such file or directory
fatal: unable to fork

Comment: Thank you! Step 6 fixed it!

Comment: `git pull --rebase origin master` solved my issue. Thanks a lot dear.

Answer (score 22):

I found the solution to this problem in GitHub help ([Dealing with non-fast-forward errors](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-non-fast-forward-errors/)):

> You can fix this by fetching and merging the changes made on the remote branch with the changes that you have made locally:
>
> ```
> $ git fetch origin
> # Fetches updates made to an online repository
> $ git merge origin branch
> # Merges updates made online with your local work
> ```
>
> Or, you can simply use git pull to perform both commands at once:
>
> ```
> $ git pull origin branch
> # Grabs online updates and merges them with your local work
> ```

Comment: This is the normal process whenever things are working as expected. It doesn't help anything when git thinks it is already up to date as @rubyandcoffee asked.

Answer (score 20):

I followed the following steps and it worked for me.

```
 rm -rf .git
 git init
 git add .
 git commit -m"first message"
 git remote add origin "LINK"
 git push -u origin master
```

Comment: this was the only solution that worked for me.

Comment: This is the final solution for beginners

Answer (score 16):

I had faced the same problem and fixed it with the below steps.

1. `git init`
2. `git add .`
3. `git commit -m 'Add your commit message'`
4. `git remote add origin https://User_name@bitbucket.org/User_name/sample.git`

   (The above URL, *https://User_name@bitbucket.org/User_name/sample.git*, refers to your [Bitbucket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitbucket) project URL)
5. `git push -u origin master`

**Hint**

Check if your GitHub account links with your local Git repository by using:

```
git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

Answer (score 15):

If you were using `git push origin master`, change it to `git push origin main` and vice versa.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64603615/2227743

Comment: Presuming GitHub'ish?

Comment: This worked for me. To change master to main I used:
$ git branch -m master main

Answer (score 14):

I got into this error today. The problem was that GitHub had an outage, and I could not push any changes, so before you start to mess up with the config, maybe check https://www.githubstatus.com.

```
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (5/5), completed with 4 local objects.
remote: fatal error in commit_refs
To github.com:REDACTED.git
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (failure)
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:REDACTED.git'
```

Comment: This was it for me

Answer (score 9):

I got this error because I tried to push without committing
So tried

> git add .
>
> git commit -m "message"
>
> git push -f

Then it worked well for me

Comment: this answer is similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41464745/11107541), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63193062/11107541), and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41127879/11107541)

Answer (score 8):

Remember to commit your changes before pushing to the GitHub repository. This might fix your problem.

Comment: this answer is expanded upon in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41464745/11107541), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63193062/11107541), and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74117926/11107541) (all later than this one was posted. moral of story: examples are valuable)

Answer (score 8):

I created an empty repository in GitHub and have my code locally. I faced the same issue now, as I followed the below sequence,

```
git init
git commit -m 'Initial Commit'
git remote add origin https://github.com/kavinraju/Repo-Name.git
git add .
git push -u origin master
```

The ***issue was***: I tried to commit *before* staging the files I have.

*So we need to stage the files and then commit*.

This is the correct sequence.

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'Initial Commit'
git remote add origin https://github.com/kavinraju/Repo-Name.git
git push -u origin master
```

Since I executed the wrong sequence first, I just executed the below commands:

```
git add .
git commit -m 'Initial Commit'
git push -u origin master
```

Answer (score 8):

Because maybe it has nothing to push (really, nothing to push). Do it like this:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/donhuvy/accounting133.git
git remote -v
git add .
git commit -m"upload"
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

Change the remote repository's URL in your case. You can skip command `git remote -v`, just for checking.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using [Gerrit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerrit_(software)), this could be caused by an inappropriate Change-id in the commit.  Try deleting the Change-Id and see what happens.

Answer (score 6):

GitHub changed the *default* branch name from *master* to *main*. So if you created the repo recently, try pushing the *main* branch.

```
git push origin main
```

This is a common mistake beginners can make.

GitHub article *[Renaming the default branch from master](https://github.com/github/renaming)*.

Answer (score 5):

Not committing initial changes before pushing also causes the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
git push origin {your_local_branch}:{your_remote_branch}
```

If your local branch and remote branch share the same name, then can you omit your local branch name. Just use `git push {your_remote_branch}`. Otherwise it will throw this error.

Answer (score 5):

Try this Git command,

```
git push origin master –f
git push origin master --force
```

Comment: error: cannot spawn sh: No such file or directory
fatal: unable to fork

Comment: "–" in "–f"  is an [em dash](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/em_dash#Noun), not [ASCII 45](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters) ("-"). I don't think it will work.

Answer (score 5):

Using a Git repository in [Azure DevOps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azure_DevOps_Server), the problem was a branch policy requiring that all changes to the branch must be made via a pull request (PR). Trying to push changes directly to the branch generated the error "failed to push some refs to ...".

I created a PR branch and pushed without problem.

Answer (score 4):

Before push, you have to add and commit the changes or do `git push -f origin master`.

Answer (score 4):

Just run these two commands if you are deploying your site on GitHub pages for the first time.

```
git commit -m "initial commit"
git push origin +HEAD
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case there was a problem with a Git `pre-push` hook.

Run `git push --verbose` to see if there are any errors.

Double check your Git hooks in the directory `.git/hooks` or move them temporarily to another place and see if everything works after that.

Answer (score 4):

Due to the recent "replacing *master* with *main* in GitHub" action, you may notice that there is a refs/heads/main if you do `git show-ref`. As a result, the following command may change from

`git push heroku master`

to

`git push heroku main`

That will solve your issue.

Answer (score 4):

In my case these two lines solved the problem.

```
git add .
git commit -m "Changes"
```

Actually, I forgot to add and commit to my changes and was just trying to push it for the first time.

```
git init
git remote add origin https://github.com/anything/repo-name.git
git add .
git commit -m "Changes"
git branch -M main
git push -u origin main
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

In my case, it was my `husky` package that disallowed the push.

```
> husky - pre-push hook failed (add --no-verify to bypass)
> husky - to debug, use 'npm run prepush'
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://username@bitbucket.org/username/my-api.git'
```

> To push it forcefully, just run `git push origin master --no-verify`

I ran `npm run prepush` to see debug the error, and this was the cause:

```
npm ERR! code ELOCKVERIFY
npm ERR! Errors were found in your npm-shrinkwrap.json, run  npm install  to fix them.
npm ERR!     Invalid: lock file's loopback-utils@0.8.3 does not satisfy loopback-utils@^0.9.0
```

Ran `npm install` and commit it, and the problem is fixed.

Comment: I had a similar issue, except the pre-push hook ran a linter, and that was failing because I hadn't installed the packages. VSCode just gave me the final git error, but when I ran the git command directly it told me about the install issue. Running yarn install sorted it.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the *branch* name prefix was already present at remote, so basically if you have a branch name 'fix' you cannot push another branch with name 'fix/new_branch_name'.

Renaming the branch solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that GitHub changed *master* to *main* made me encounter this issue. So from now on, the solution to push to origin is:

```
git push -u origin main
```

Comment: Do you means the remote repo on GitHub has only a branch main, not master? I have created a brand new repo on GitHub, and its main branch remains... master (for now)

Answer (score 3):

These steps worked for me:

1. Switch to current branch & pull latest code
2. Rename local branch

   `git branch -m [new-name]`
3. Push local branch to server

   `git push origin [new-name]`
4. Remove branch from server

   `git push origin --delete [old-name]`

Comment: Why did you need to rename a local branch?

Answer (score 3):

By following the documentation, you just need to `pull` and `push` it to your Github project.

```
git init -b main

git add . && git commit -m "Commit Here"

git remote add origin  <REMOTE_URL>

git remote -v

git pull origin main

git push origin main
```

Here are some of my solutions dealing with this kind of problems:

> fatal: unable to access <REMOTE_URL>: The requested URL returned error: 400

```
git remote set-url origin <REMOTE_URL>
```

> fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories

```
git pull origin main --allow-unrelated-histories
```

> error: pathspec did not match any file(s) known to git

```
git fetch origin <branch_name>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `git-with-ssh`, one reason why it's not working is it maybe pointing to wrong `ssh-private-key`  file or `correct-file-wrong-private-key`. If I remember correctly, I had recently added the `ssh-private-key` with some difficulty. So I cleared the `sshe-agents` by

```
ssh-add -D
```

Then everything worked!

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? What is it supposed to do? Why is it necessary? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/43190763/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 2):

Creating a new branch solved it for me:

```
git checkout -b <nameOfNewBranch>
```

As expected, there isn’t any need to merge since the previous branch was fully contained in the new one.

Comment: I had this issue exactly, I was on feature22 and was doing `git push origin feature22-fix`, but `feature22-fix` didn't exit neither local nor remote, so I had to first checkout the 
branch locally, then push

Answer (score 2):

It may happen when you don't have any files.
Try to create a text file, and then follow the following commands:

```
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem was I did not *add* the files before the commit.

`git add .`

`git commit -m "your msg"`

Answer (score 2):

Do these:

```
git rm --cached *
git add .
git commit -m"upload"
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? What is it supposed to do? Why are all those steps and command-line options necessary? Why does it work? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58025637/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 2):

Best use `rm -rf .git/hooks` and then try git push

Comment: Interesting, it helped me in a case, where there were clearly no commits on origin (no need to rebase).

Comment: Why would you toss out all your hooks? maybe make a backup first?

Comment: Deleting all the Git hooks just because they prevent you from committing? Better find the real reason.

Answer (score 2):

I created a custom pre-push file, and I forgot to end it with `exit 0`.

That caused me to get this "failed to push some refs" error. I added `exit 0` to the end of my pre-push hook and, of course, it works fine now.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
git push -f origin master
```

This one is write.

Comment: What do you mean by *"This one is write."*? Do you mean *"This one is right."*? Or something else?

Answer (score 2):

The issue at times may be caused by a system outage on Github. Always check on the GitHub status page https://www.githubstatus.com/ to verify if all systems are operational.

Comment: This is a duplicate answer. Before posting make sure you check to see if someone else has already provided the same solution.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this applies, but the fix for me was to commit something locally after *git init*.  Then I pushed to remote using *--set-upstream*.

Answer (score 1):

If you are attempting to initialize a directory with an existing GitHub repository, you should ensure you are committing changes.

Try creating a file:

```
touch initial
git add initial
git commit -m "initial commit"
git push -u origin master
```

That will place a file named initial that you can delete later.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I could not solve the problem with the other solutions, but my problem was that the branch name I wanted to push was not accepted by remote. I changed it to the correct format, and it was accepted.

It was `test/testing_routes`, and I needed to change it to `testing_route` in which the forward slash (`/`) is not allowed by remote.

You should ensure that the branch name format is correct.

Answer (score 1):

This issue comes when the remote server has some extra commit which is not available in your working directory. Below is the solution to fix this issue.

1. To get the latest code from the remote server to local and then push, do

   ```
   git pull
   git push
   ```
2. Directly do the force push to the remote server.

   ```
   git push --force
   ```

If #1 will not work, then use the #2 option.

Use the below command to get all the options that are related to push:

```
git push --help
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I misspelled the name of the branch.  Locally I did something like:

`git push --set-upstream origin feture/my-feature`

where my branch name was missing the `a` in `feature`.  I corrected it to:

`git push --set-upstream origin feature/my-feature`

And everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

In our case, retrying to push solved the problem. Probably a network slowness caused the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I missed amending. I just needed to run `git commit --amend` and then push. It fixed the issue. It might help someone who has previously committed code.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the 'git push origin main' and then got the message. Then I tried 'git push' alone, but it was not working.

I checked if I had committed to be sure (yes). I tried the 'pull' and then 'push' again, but nope.

And before starting some stunts, I just closed and opened a new terminal and then 'push' again and it worked :p

Answer (score 1):

Check if your Internet connection is working fine and has got good speed.

I was trying to push with my [4G](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4G) mobile hotspot and getting this error for nearly 10 minutes.

P.S. Here in India, we get [3G](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3G) speed for a 4G network, so before doing something fancy; just see if there is reasonable speed available :)

Comment: Still, 3G should be more than sufficient. Perhaps extreme congestion (long latency)? What are the 'ping' times?

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced this issue when using the command.

`git push -u origin main`

So I cleared all cache of npm using `npm cache clean --force` and tried to push again. That's worked for me.

Comment: *How* did you *"clear the cache of GitHub*? What did you do?

Comment: Thanks, @PeterMortensen, I have just edited my previous answer.

Comment: Sounds strange, but it worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Steps to push :

```
git init
git add README.md      -------- or --------   git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin 'http github link'
git push -u origin main       ------ or -------    git push -f origin master
```

If branch is on main, hence:

```
git push -u origin main
```

for master :

```
git push -f origin master
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer is not for this specific question but may help someone with the same error.
If you are doing `add .` , `commit` and `push` on an empty directory, you will probably get the same error. After building the Github repository, run these codes in the local directory. The point is that you need to add/create a file and commit this change before pushing the repository to the remote.

```
echo "# something" >> README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git branch -M main
git remote add origin https://github.com/[address of your repository].git
git push -u origin main
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I found out I was pushing the wrong branch name

The branch I'm pushing is `release/2.2.1` but my branch name is `release/2.2.l`
so I change it using this command `git branch -m old-name new-name`.
Now it's working.

Answer (score 1):

`git gc` has worked for me.

Extra characters b/c 30 is the minimum.

Comment: didn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

if you are using powershell i will recommend use git bash it is available in vs code

1. switch to git bash
2. check ls -a (it will show hidden file)
3. if you find .git file remove using rm -rf .git
4. then git init
5. git add .
6. git commit -m "message"
7. git remote add origin "https://.............."
8. git branch -M main
9. git push -u origin main

Answer (score 0):

You need to give some force

**Just do push --force.**

Comment: That sounds dangerous. Can you explain why that is necessary and what the implications are? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55469180/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0):

For [Sourcetree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlassian#Acquisitions_and_product_announcements) users

First do an initial commit or make sure you don't have any uncommitted changes. Then at the side of Sourcetree there is a "REMOTES". Right-click on it, and then click 'Push to origin'. There you go.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that (strangely) there was no branch called *master*. I took the repository from GitHub.

Comment: What was the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I was pushing an existing branch with a typo, 'evelop', which I did not have checked out yet, and instead, I wanted to push a branch called 'envelope'.

So the branch must exist and checked out at the local working copy in order to be able to be pushed, of course. Therefore the solution to that error is to not make a typo.

Answer (score 0):

You will also get this error if you created an empty repo and forgot to use

```
git init
```

first before pushing your first commit.

Answer (score 0):

is your push linked with your jira story. if yes check the jira work flow condtion.
the admin may configure to allow only push only based on some work flow.

Answer (score 0):

Try With

```
git status
```

It will show like this **Your branch is based on 'origin/main', but the upstream is gone.**

Then follow below steps

```
git branch --unset-upstream
git push --set-upstream origin main
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case: a `tag` was named the same as an existing `branch`. Renaming the branch (`git checkout` with an other name) and removing the clashing named branch (`git branch -d $branchname`) solved the issue: git pushing the tag went ok.

Answer (score -1):

*git error: failed to push some refs to* also comes when the local repository name does match with the corresponding remote repository name. Make sure you are working on the correct pair of repository before you pull changes to remote repository.

In case you spell it incorrectly and you want to remove the local repository, use the following steps.

Remove the local repository on Windows:

1. `del /F /S /Q /A .git`
2. `rmdir .git`
3. Correct the local folder name (`XXXX02`->`XXXX20`) or if it is a newly created repo delete it and recreate the repo (`XXXX02` Repo name changed to `XXXX20`).
4. `git init`
5. Remap with remote repo if it is not mapped.
6. `git remote add origin https://github.com/<username>/XXXX20.git`
7. `git push -u origin master`

Answer (score -1):

For me I just had to checkout into another branch and then comeback, and then it worked, I could push with no issues.

Please try the simple things before using `--force` and such

Answer (score -1):

### Works in Github

I'm assuming that you're utilizing GitHub for your repo.

A potential, albeit rare, cause of the error you're encountering might be due to protective rules set on the branch to which you are pushing, which you may have inadvertently forgotten about.

If this is the case, to resolve it, it's necessary to completely remove these rules. Merely editing the rule or deselecting options within the rule page is insufficient to address the issue.

### Step 1:

Go to the "Setting" of the repo

[image]

### Step 2:

In "Code and automation" menu find the "Branches" item

[image]

### step 3:

You should verify whether there's a match between the existing rule patterns and your branch name. If you find a match, delete that rule as demonstrated in the picture above.

**Remember** to capture a screenshot of the configured rules before you delete them.

### step 4:

Since you're removing the protection rule temporarily, it implies you understand your actions and might need to reestablish that rule following your push operation.

### Note

To resolve the error, you might consider editing the rule by unchecking the active boxes; however, this approach is ineffective. Only complete delete works!

[image]

Answer (score -1):

My case here is that I am trying to upload **files that are too large** at the same time.

So the problem is solved when they are split and uploaded separately.

---

Update

Hi @JeremyCaney, thank you for your kind reminder. Please find further elaboration below.

**1. Certainty of approach uniqueness:**
I can confirm that the approach I presented earlier has not been previously provided for this specific question.

**2. Distinction of approach:**
While the uniqueness of my approach may not be the primary focus, it is worth noting that the reason behind the 'git error: failed to push some refs to remote' can vary, and the solution I offered addresses one possible cause.

**3. Preferred circumstances for the approach:**
This approach is particularly effective for handling large files. Although I cannot provide an exact file size threshold, based on my experience, I have encountered difficulties when attempting to upload files of approximately 4GB at once.

**4. Insufficiency of previous answers:**
The previous answers provided effective solutions for most issues, but unfortunately, they did not address the specific problem I encountered.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35520973)

Answer (score -3):

Getting an error on `git push -u origin main`? Try this solution. It will work 100%.

> **git push origin master**, change it to **git push origin main**

How to change Main?

> **git branch -M main**