# How to fix failed to local refs git error?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am trying to push some changes from my local feature branch to remote but keep on getting the following message

git.exe push --all --progress  "origin"

```
Counting objects: 52, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (14/14), done.
Writing objects: 100% (15/15), 1.52 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 15 (delta 10), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: failed to lock refs/heads/develop/feature_123
To https://bitbucket.org/xxx/abcd
! [remote rejected] develop/feature_123 -> develop/feature_123 (failed to lock)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://bitbucket.org/xxx/abcd'


git did not exit cleanly (exit code 1) (36302 ms @ 10/15/2014 5:53:11 PM)
```

I have looked around the google and here at stackoverflow. Found some solutions and tried applying all. However none of those worked for me. Does anyone know exactly why I get this error message on git push? I am using Tortoisegit. I tried using sourcecontrol . Same thing...

Comment: This won't help you directly, but: the error is coming from bitbucket.org, not from git.  (Or rather, not from *your* git; bitbucket.org may also be running git and then it's coming from *their* git.)  I have no idea why bitbucket.org is giving you this error, though.

Comment: are you sure, you have appropriate permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried pulling from remote repository first? If so and you are sure that you have the latest version from remote repository, you can also try `git push -f`
Probably, this may help you: [git error: failed to push some refs to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114676/git-error-failed-to-push-some-refs-to)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. I could not create a repo like develop/feature_123.. when I created the repo like feature_123 and not under develop, it worked.