# Push rejected, failed to compile Python app. Django, Ubuntu

Tags: python, django, git, heroku, deployment

I'm following this tutorial from Getting Started with Django - http://gettingstartedwithdjango.com/en/lessons/introduction-and-launch/

And I got stuck when I try to deploy the code. That's what I get when I try to `git push heroku master`

```
git push heroku master

Counting objects: 16, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (14/14), done.
Writing objects: 100% (16/16), 8.19 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 16 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing runtime (python-2.7.9)
remote: -----> Noticed cffi. Bootstrapping libffi.
remote: -----> Installing dependencies with pip
remote:        Collecting abstract-rendering==0.5.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:          Downloading abstract_rendering-0.5.1.tar.gz
remote:            Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
remote:            Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:              File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-build-_xo9ib/abstract-rendering/setup.py", line 6, in <module>
remote:                from numpy import get_include
remote:            ImportError: No module named numpy
remote:            
remote:            ----------------------------------------
remote:     Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-_xo9ib/abstract-rendering
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to thawing-tor-5626.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/thawing-tor-5626.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/thawing-tor-5626.git'
```

And here is what I have in `requirements.txt` file:

```
abstract-rendering==0.5.1
argcomplete==0.8.4
astropy==1.0.1
backports.ssl-match-hostname==3.4.0.2
bcolz==0.8.1
beautifulsoup4==4.3.2
binstar==0.10.1
bitarray==0.8.1
blaze==0.7.3
blz==0.6.2
bokeh==0.8.1
boto==2.36.0
cdecimal==2.3
certifi==14.5.14
cffi==0.9.2
clyent==0.3.4
colorama==0.3.3
conda==3.10.0
conda-build==1.11.0
conda-env==2.1.3
configobj==5.0.6
cryptography==0.8
Cython==0.22
cytoolz==0.7.2
DataShape==0.4.4
decorator==3.4.0
Django==1.8.1
docutils==0.12
enum34==1.0.4
fastcache==1.0.2
Flask==0.10.1
funcsigs==0.4
futures==2.2.0
gevent==1.0.1
gevent-websocket==0.9.3
greenlet==0.4.5
grin==1.2.1
h5py==2.4.0
ipython==3.0.0
itsdangerous==0.24
jdcal==1.0
jedi==0.8.1
Jinja2==2.7.3
jsonschema==2.4.0
llvmlite===0.2.2-1-gbcb15be
lxml==3.4.2
MarkupSafe==0.23
matplotlib==1.4.3
mistune==0.5.1
mock==1.0.1
multipledispatch==0.4.7
networkx==1.9.1
nltk==3.0.2
nose==1.3.4
numba==0.17.0
numexpr==2.3.1
numpy==1.9.2
odo==0.3.1
openpyxl==1.8.5
pandas==0.15.2
patsy==0.3.0
pep8==1.6.2
Pillow==2.7.0
ply==3.4
psutil==2.2.1
ptyprocess==0.4
py==1.4.26
pyasn1==0.1.7
pycosat==0.6.1
pycparser==2.10
pycrypto==2.6.1
pycurl==7.19.5.1
pyflakes==0.8.1
Pygments==2.0.2
pyOpenSSL==0.14
pyparsing==2.0.3
pytest==2.6.4
python-dateutil==2.4.1
pytz==2015.2
PyYAML==3.11
pyzmq==14.5.0
redis==2.10.3
requests==2.6.0
rope==0.9.4
runipy==0.1.3
scikit-image==0.11.2
scikit-learn==0.15.2
scipy==0.15.1
six==1.9.0
sockjs-tornado==1.0.1
Sphinx==1.2.3
spyder==2.3.4
SQLAlchemy==0.9.9
statsmodels==0.6.1
sympy==0.7.6
tables==3.1.1
terminado==0.5
Theano==0.6.0
toolz==0.7.1
tornado==4.1
ujson==1.33
unicodecsv==0.9.4
Werkzeug==0.10.1
xlrd==0.9.3
XlsxWriter==0.6.7
xlwt==0.7.5
```

`procfile` - `web: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT --noreload`
`.gitignore` - `*.pyc`

I am new with Git, so any kind of help would be appreciated.
I am using Ubuntu 14.04.
If there's a need of other information please just let me know.
Thank you!

Comment: Do you really need all those packages for your Django app? Or are they just the result of not using a virtualenv, and therefore outputting everything installed on your local machine when you do `pip freeze`?

Comment: Seems similar to this thread [here][1]. Are there new commits on master that are not in your local repo?

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114676/git-error-failed-to-push-some-refs-to

Comment: Before getting started with Django I studied data science, where author of the book recommended me to install Anaconda, I guess that's the reason why so many of them are on that list.

Comment: Fine. But that's why - as that very tutorial explains - you should use a virtualenv, so that it only contains the packages you actually need (which in your case is probably just Django).