# Fatal unable to read git

Tags: git, bitbucket

Hi I have been trying to solve the problem. I tried many ways `git fsck`. But I am not able to push my local changes to the bitbucket. When I try to push. The error comes as :

```
$ git push origin master
Counting objects: 128, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (114/114), done.
fatal: unable to read 6e9b01e1971662fb2796aeb85f4fc9c1c54c182b
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: write error: Bad file descriptor
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://sushilsth21@bitbucket.org/sushilsth21/bijuli-bazaar.git'
```

Please Help. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git error: failed to push some refs to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114676/git-error-failed-to-push-some-refs-to)

Comment: I don't think its duplicates of mentioned question. Mine problem is related with missing objects.

Comment: Your probably right.  Out of curiosity.. is this a node project?

Comment: Node project means?

Comment: node.js javascript. what language is this project in.

Comment: Just a swag, but was trying to look through git sources for where that error comes from. I wonder if you can repack your repo "git repack" and retry. If not, can you find that file under .git/objects/6e/9b01e1971662fb2796aeb85f4fc9c1c54c182b and see that the file is readable if it hasnt been packed . I wonder if you can make a local clone of your repo and if that would produce the same error, and if not, push from there.

Comment: I cannot see these file in the directory. I think it was delete when I did `git fsck`. Is there any other way to resolve the problem.