# How can I fix "refusing to merge unrelated histories" when uploading a project to GitHub?

Tags: git, github, git-bash

I have installed [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/) and Git on a Windows machine. I got a GitHub account and created a dummy repository.

When I intend to upload my package through the [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway) command line, it fails with an error:

```
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

I used several ways to overcome these issues by using an existing solution from this community, but still it didn't fix the problem. Is there a trick of working this problem? How can I upload my projects to GitHub successfully?

Comment: All these answers assume you don't want anything from the initial github repo, but github can add files for you, like a default, nicely formatted .gitignore and README. The only way I could find to get around this is an extra `git merge --allow-unrelated-histories`. I wish there were a way to do this in a single `git pull`.

Comment: `git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories` .See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37937984/git-refusing-to-merge-unrelated-histories-on-rebase

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git refusing to merge unrelated histories on rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37937984/git-refusing-to-merge-unrelated-histories-on-rebase)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

```
cd /path/to/my/repo
git init
git add --all
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git remote add origin <remote repo URL>
git push -u origin master
```

Be sure to replace `/path/to/my/repo` with the path to your repository directory (e.g., `C:\Users\jvrat\Documents\MSPC`), and `<remote repository URL>` with the URL to your remote repository (e.g., `https://github.com/username/repo_name.git`).

Comment: can't finish rm -r .git command yet. Plus, git add all gave me an error. Any further solution ?

Comment: Does the error message say anything more? You can try [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114676/git-error-failed-to-push-some-refs-to)

Comment: your solution is quite helpful, the last comment is useful. Thank you :)

Comment: Plus, where can I find useful git command when I am interacting github if any new commit is taken place ? Any useful git command you could recommend ? Thanks your big help :)

Comment: Just google ["git tutorial"](https://www.google.pl/search?q=git+tutorial), and you'll find a lot of them. Github has [its own interactive git tutorial](https://try.github.io) too. For reference purposes it's best to use [official git docs](https://git-scm.com/docs).

Answer (score 18):

I am just sharing that rebasing worked for me. I had a new project on GitHub, and a new repository locally that I wanted to link up and kept getting `fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories`. What worked:

```
git remote add origin http://github.com/MyName/MyProjectName -f
git branch -u origin/master
git pull -r     # R for rebase, makes the magic happen
```

Output:

```
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: Initial Commit
```

`git log` output (the first is the GitHub repository, and the second is local):

```
c7f843e Initial Commit (AmitaiB, 4 minutes ago)
97100be Initial commit (Amitai Blickstein, 9 minutes ago)
```

PS: It is funny; I never noticed that the default initial commit message from GitHub is **I**nitial **C**ommit, whereas the local one is **I**nitial **c**ommit (lowercase). I think I'll send that question in to Jack Handey...

Comment: Who is Jack Handy? Do you mean [Jack Handey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Handey)?

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to initialise Git inside your local project directory:

```
git init
```

After that, your directory is a local Git repository and contains a *.git* directory.

You then basically create files and add it to your repository via

```
git add <file-name>
```

Files added to your repository are tracked now. If you want to commit all the changes you made to the files you added, you just need to

```
git commit "Commit message"
```

These all reside in your local Git repository.

To connect your local repository to a remote one you have to issue another command:

```
git remote add origin <remote repo URL>
```

'origin' and the following URL represent the remote name and its URL.
You are now able to push your local changes to your *origin* repository via

```
git push <remote-name> <branch-name>
```

which is in your case

```
git push origin master
```

because for now you just have the *master* branch.

You can check the status of your local repository and its connected remote repository via

```
git status
```

Comment: Try a 'git pull' to incorporate changes from your remote repo first.

Comment: still can't solved. Could you give me alternative solution please ?

Comment: Just create a new folder, navigate to it via CLI and issue a 'git clone <repo-URL>' after that just issue 'git init'. You now have local git repo in sync with your origin.