# Bit bucket git bash issue

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-bash

Hi i am trying to update files from my local to bit bucket through Git Bash. When i try this commend

```
$ git push -u origin 'master'
```

I get an error like

```
To https://test@bitbucket.org/test/a.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://test@bitbucket.org/test/a.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Please help me.I don't know why i am getting this error.I am beginner in git Bash and bit bucket.Please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `local/master` is not update with `remote/master`. First Pull master then Push.

```
$ git pull origin master
$ git push -u origin master
```

If not work then try to rebase origin/master.

```
$ git pull --rebase origin master
```

---

As you mentioned (in comment), you have `untracked files` locally. Follow `Add -> Commit -> Rebase -> Push`.

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'added all'
$ git pull --rebase origin master
$ git push origin master
```

Comment: Was you `git pull ..` success? What is the output of `git status` ?

Comment: if i tried git commit -m 'commit to master'   i get "nothing added to commit but untracked files present" @sajid khan

Comment: Add untracked files first. `git add .`, `git commit -m 'message'`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114676/git-error-failed-to-push-some-refs-to did not help you? what is the result of `git status`?

Comment: @ASR i get an error                                                                 On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to incllike ude in what will be committed)

Comment: @ASR i refer the link which you mentioned.But bad luck

Comment: Does `git status` shows a list of untracked files? if yes then just do `git add .`(only if you want to commit them)

Comment: @sajibkhan khan i get an message like On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean

Comment: Ok. Commit is successful, now I think you did push successfully, right?

Comment: @sajibkhan TThanks