# Git failed to push, but actually pushed

Tags: git, tfs, tortoisegit

If I try to push any my commit, then I receive the next error:

```
git.exe push --progress "origin" master:master

Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 7.54 MiB | 240 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://...'
```

I checked in git log, and it still shows that my commit is not on the remote server. But tricky part is that it actually pushed. If I try to clone this repository to new folder, then I can receive my previosly pushed files.

If I will use fetch command then remote/origin is automatically switched to my commit in log.

We are using TFS GIT as a server and TorotoiseGit as a GUI for git.

Comment: The issue was in some mess at git config files. I just replaced my own configs with one from my collegue. Unfortunetaly, I didn't find which settings caused that issue.

Comment: *Before* that error message, Git prints informative messages about what it *could* push and what it *could not* push. Those are what you should pay attention to—the final message is merely a summary, pointing out that there are earlier messages that need attending.

Comment: Added full message from git

Comment: Hm, that's rather peculiar. There should be lines of the form: `d1574b8..11ae6ca  master -> master` or `! [rejected] master -> master`. It seems that perhaps there is a bug in your Git, that it doesn't print these.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you didn't synchronize the remote repository with local repo. You can roll back Git to your previous commit without changing the files, then creating a new commit:

```
git reset --mixed origin/master
git add .
git commit -m "xx"
git push origin master
```

More information, check this case: [git error: failed to push some refs to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114676/git-error-failed-to-push-some-refs-to)

Comment: This happens on fresh cloned (test) repository. So I cloned repository, commited my changes, and pushing it failed. Noone pushing anything before me to this repository.

Comment: Did you get the error in TorotoiseGit? Did you try with git command line?

Comment: I added a full message to main post. Yes, with command line I get the same output.

Comment: How about only use "git push origin master"?