# GitHub: failed to push some refs when I init a new android project

Tags: git, github

I was just starting a new android studio project. Executed

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "First Commit
git remote add origin http://....
```

and successfully create a remote thread to push.
The GitHub repository of my project had already been created, and had been added 3 files including .gitignore license & README by default. Then I executed this:

```
git push origin master
```

That's when the err coming...
I can't push as usual even after I executed

```
git pull origin master
```

They just claimed that there's another tip behind my branch, perhaps because the pull order added a new branch called origin/master and now I'm confused with it.
In fact, I tried push -f once but it didn't ends well because my default files in the GitHub repository were deleted by doing so.
Are there any solutions could let me both keep my repository files and push my commits successfully?

Comment: I think the easiest thing to do would be to `git clone` your project into a new folder on your computer, move your files, then recreate your first commit.

Comment: That works surely but I think that would not be a general solution.

Comment: Only reason I mentioned it is because you don't really have a history of commits you need to save.

Comment: Yeah that's would be the easiest way in this case for sure

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git error: failed to push some refs to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114676/git-error-failed-to-push-some-refs-to) - if this post doesn't help you @J.Titus's suggestion seems good.

Comment: That helps, thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

Sure, easy as pie:

```
git fetch origin
git checkout origin/master
git cherry-pick master
git branch -f master
git checkout master
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: What does "cherry-pick" do? Seems like it doesn't work

Comment: After executed your code, seems like my local directory left nothing but those 3 default files

Comment: The cherry-pick takes the commit you tell it and applies it on top of your current commit, hence your "First Commit" that adds your files. If it "does not work", tell me the error message.

Comment: Alright, I solved it by using --rebase and --unrelated-histories after git pull. Thanks anyway.