# Git Push Error: failed to push some refs to?

Tags: git, github

I am trying to git push from my local repo (TEST) to remote branch (TEST-tapariak) using following command:

```
git push origin TEST:TEST-tapariak
```

I am getting following error:

```
To ssh://git.example.com:2222/pkg/PARISService
 ! [rejected]        TEST -> TEST-tapariak (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git.example.com:2222/pkg/PARISService'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I saw [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114676/git-error-failed-to-push-some-refs-to) and did git pull --rebase, git pull --rebase origin TEST, and git pull --rebase origin TEST-tapariak but didn't work for me.

Can anyone guide me how to resolve this?

Comment: It seems like there are commits on the `Test-tapariak` branch that are not local. Run this git log command `git log --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --all` look to see if the branches are out of sync. (Some one may have committed to the remote branch without you knowing)

Comment: Try `git pull --rebase origin TEST-tapariak:TEST` first.

Answer (score 4):

use this command to upload full project forcefully,

```
git push -u origin master -f
```

Answer (score 1):

> hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.

Pull remote `TEST-tapariak` branch into local `TEST` branch first, then Push.

```
$ git pull origin TEST-tapariak
$ git push origin TEST:TEST-tapariak
```

Comment: when i do git pull: From .
 * branch            TEST-tapariak -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date

Comment: I guess, For `git pull` it tries `git pull origin TEST` because it is tracking remote branch `TEST`, not `TEST-tapariak`. So, `git pull origin TEST-tapariak` should run actually. Does it work?

Answer (score 1):

Go to master do `git pull`
then comeback to your branch and do: `git rebase -i master`
If there are any conflicts:

1. Resolve them
2. Do `git add --all`
3. Then `git rebase --continue`

Finally do `git push`

Answer (score 0):

Can you do the following:

```
git pull --rebase origin TEST-tapariak
```

And finally,

```
git push origin TEST:TEST-tapariak
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case what I was doing wrong was trying to push to the `gh-pages` branch from my `master` branch.

`git checkout -b gh-pages`

This worked for me. Just saying, this simple thing could also be the case.

Answer (score 0):

It should also be recommended to ensure GitHub is actually up before trying anything else.  I encountered this issue during an outage and would use the following page to perform a quick check before trying anything else in future.

https://www.githubstatus.com/