# Unable to push folder to github

Tags: git, github

- created a folder Homepage3 with 2 subfolders Client & Server
- ran `git init`
- created a repository Homepage3 in github

in my Homepage3 folder ran...

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/myusername/Homepage3.git
git push -u origin master
```

> error: failed to push some refs to
>   'https://github.com/myusername/Homepage3.git'

**Whats wrong??**

Comment: Is either folder empty?

Comment: not empty, not empty,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git error: failed to push some refs to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114676/git-error-failed-to-push-some-refs-to)

Comment: there is no solution - i dont understand why, tried everything in that post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to first clone your repository.

```
git clone https://username@bitbucket.org/username/Homepage3.git
```

than move your folder(Homepage3) inside the cloned repository
than use 'git add' command to add those folders and than use the commands
to puse the updates.

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/myusername/Homepage3.git
git push -u origin master
```