# How to fix : failed to push some refs to gitlab?

Tags: git, gitlab

I tried to push the project to the repository of GitLab but there was an error occurred.

```
To https://gitlab.com/codersclan-interviews-frontend/codersclan-david-rose.git
 ! [remote rejected] test -> test (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://gitlab.com/codersclan-interviews-frontend/codersclan-david-rose.git'
```

How can I fix this?

Git repository wasn't created by me, it was created by the client.
And he asked me to push the code to the branch which I made by myself and let him know when I finish.

To do this task, I did like following

```
git clone https://gitlab.com/codersclan-interviews-frontend/codersclan-david-rose.git
git checkout -b 'test'
git branch test
add project
git add .
git commit -m "..."
git push origin test
```

I expected the successful push result but the above error occurred.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114676/git-error-failed-to-push-some-refs-to

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I fix [an error of the form `pre-receive hook declined`]?
>
> [The] Git repository wasn't created by me, it was created by the client.

In general, *you* **cannot** fix this.  Only the owner of the repository can do that, because a pre-receive hook is something *they* control and you don't.

A pre-receive hook is basically a verifier, a sort of policeman of push requests.  He—if we can anthropomorphize this hook—inspects your push request in any way he's told.  Typically, he'd look at each of the commits you propose to add to the repository, but without any information or hint as to what kind of checks this pre-receive hook was told to perform, *we*—the people reading your question—cannot guess what inspections he might be doing.  Nor can you, for that matter: you can only know what *he* tells you.

So: did he tell you anything?  Did he say: "I don't like your commit because _____"? (fill in the blank)  If so, pay attention to that announcement.  But if he didn't tell you anything, well, we can't either.  That's not your fault: anyone writing a custom GitLab hook of this sort *must* tell their users why they're rejecting the commit, otherwise everyone is in the dark.

See also https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/server_hooks.html (but you'd have to be the administrator of the repository to fix the problem).

Comment: I am having this problem even though I am the admin...

Comment: @Wallflower: in that case, you need to fix up your program so that it tells you why you're rejecting your own things. :-)

Comment: same issue and I am the owner

Comment: #metoo, i have no hooks just a simple repo as owner :(

Answer (score 6):

This could also happen as a result of a protected branch name. Try changing your branch name to something that isn't a protected name on the remote repository. hotfix, development and the likes may be protected names.

Comment: +1 for mentioning protected branches. Unlike Github, Gitlab keeps you from for instance forced pushing when the branch is protected. The main branch is protected by default.

Comment: i changed my branch name from "main" to "master" and it solved my problem. thanks.

Comment: My GitLab repo is new and the code is coming from an old repo.

Answer (score 2):

For me, I had to create the main branch and push again as we normally push commands -

Create the main branch -

```
git branch -M main
```

Push the changes -

```
git push -u origin main
```

Answer (score 1):

You forget to do:

```
git add .
git commit -m "message"
git remote add origin https://gitlab.com/*******.git
git branch -M main
git push -uf origin main
```

Comment: `git push -uf origin main` this works for me but do it have to use `git push -uf origin main` everytime I pushed to main? i used to just `git push --force-with-lease`

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue and solved it by checkout to another branch.

For example:
git checkout -b develop

Then,
git push -uf origin develop

The problem was "You are not allowed to force push code to a protected branch on this project", message by Gitlab.