# How to push or commit into someone repo?

Tags: github

So I have my Project located in

```sh
C:\Users\user\Desktop\2.0\Qualitätskontrolle
```

And I want to push it to the bosses repo using GitBash.

Right now I have managed to cd across the Project Folder But I have no idea how to push or commit it to the bosses repo.

I have tried:

```sh
git push -u origin
```

But that wrote following exception:

```sh
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/KlausK04/Qualitaetskontrolle.git'
```

Comment: Could you please post the complete output? (any message after the error that might further pinpoint to the cause). It is possible that you need to do a `git pull` first, if your local repository is not in sync with the github repo. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24114676/5987698) may also be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it now myself. No need to worry anymore.

i used the extension on Visual Studio in order to push it to the repo via Sync.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain how you fixed your issue, it may be of help to somebody else with the same question.