# Push my cloud server project to my github repository by using command line

Tags: laravel, github, upload, push, commit

I want to push my project from server to github repository and for that i have created one private repository on github and my project uploaded on cloud server. How can i upload or push whole project to github repository? When i try to push command then i am getting below error:

```
error: src refspec HEAD does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/laravel/TestProject.git'
```

Please provide me steps to push project to github. I am using putty with SSH for connect to server.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114676/git-error-failed-to-push-some-refs-to

Comment: Hello  AlbertoSinigaglia, Do you have experience on github?

Comment: There are several steps to follow, so you will need to tell us what you have done so far. For example: Do you already have ssh keys configured in your repository and on the server? you can know by executing this command on the server `ssh -T -p 443 git@ssh.github.com` https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/using-ssh-over-the-https-port