# I am getting error while pushing code to github using Github Desktop, Failed to push some refs

Tags: github, git-commit, lint, git-push, github-desktop

I am getting this error while pushing code to github using github desktop. I have attached the image.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was unable to push using github but found a way around. I have pushed code for this particular project using command line (git bash). Initially git bash was throwing the same error "failed to push some refs". It was my husky package, which was not allowing to push. I used the following command.

```
To push it forcefully, just run git push origin master --no-verify
```

And use this to check your problem `I ran npm run prepush to see debug the error`

Well I had some linting errors because of the theme I am using ngx-admin.

If I come across permanent solution after linting issue I will update this but this is working perfectly for now.

You can also see this post for reference. I got hint from one of the answers.
[failed to push some Refs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114676/git-error-failed-to-push-some-refs-to)