# is there any solution available app not compatible with buildpack

Tags: django, python-3.x, heroku

```
  (pdjangoenv) C:\Users\bhvbh\Desktop\practice django\dental_john>git push heroku master

    Enumerating objects: 208, done.
    Counting objects: 100% (208/208), done.
    Delta compression using up to 4 threads

Compressing objects: 100% (201/201), done.
Writing objects: 100% (208/208), 2.88 MiB | 47.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 208 (delta 26), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack- 
registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
remote:        More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to dentist-yash.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/dentist-yash.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/dentist-yash.git'
```

> I am trying to deploy my app in heroku, but is failing with "App not compatible with buildpack" error. I have added requirement.txt and procfile in my project, yet it is failing.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure are you all merged and working off the master branch in git. Also make sure the git repo is initialized within the project root folder for example it might might be dental_john versus dentist-yash.

Checkout this other pos for the git error you are getting

error: **failed to push some refs** to 'https://git.heroku.com/dentist-yash.git'

[git error: failed to push some refs to remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114676/git-error-failed-to-push-some-refs-to-remote)