# Git remote keeps getting rejected when pushing to heroku

Tags: spring, git, spring-boot, heroku

I am currently learning Git and Heroku.

I'm at the point where I have created a Spring Boot project, initialized Git, and created an application on Heroku.

Now when I add all files, everything works. I commit the changes, no flaws, and lastly I set-up a remote to my .git.

This is where my error occurs. When I push my project onto my git, I get an error saying:

```
To https://git.heroku.com/heroku-boottest.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/heroku-boottest.git'
```

Keep in mind that my git is empty. I haven't pushed anything else onto the git.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please share the command you are using for the push.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issue!

For some reason heroku didn't want me to use JDK 14, so I changed my pom.xml to jdk 8

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114676/git-error-failed-to-push-some-refs-to-remote).

> If the GitHub repo has seen new commits pushed to it, while you were
>   working locally, I would advise using:
>
> ```
> git pull --rebase
> git push
> ```

Comment: The problem is that my git repo was empty. Nothing has been comitted yet so there is nothing to pull.