# error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/XXXXXXXXX.com

Tags: git, github, push, git-push, git-pull

```
$ git push -u origin master
To https://github.com/XXXXXXXXX.com/FirstRepo.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/XXXXXXXXX.com/FirstRepo.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

**I am using github for the first time today, I had already checked other answers out of which only one seems to work and that is using 'git push origin master --force', but by doing this it is deleting all other commits. So can anyone please tell me the solution for this.**

Comment: Did you pull first?

Comment: You can do git pull to fetch the remote changes then your push should work

Comment: yeah I did that before pushing, but still it's giving the same hints.But during commit its showing like this " create mode 100644 textfile.txt"

Comment: If you did `git pull` first, it sounds like something went wrong.  Post more details.  Show your steps, show the output, and then maybe we can help you work through it.  At the moment, the best advice anyone can give is "use `git pull` first", then push.

Comment: You could try this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114676/git-error-failed-to-push-some-refs-to-remote

Answer (score 5):

If your `local` branch is behind your `remote` branch and have some commits on top of it, then you can solve your problem by running the following commands.

```sh
$ git pull origin master --rebase
$ git push origin master
```

**NB**: If you only run `git pull` without `--rebase`, then it will add a `merge` commit which you probably don't want.

Answer (score 1):

Just run this code in terminal .

```
git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories
```

or if you use main branch run this code

```
git pull origin main --allow-unrelated-histories
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it sounds like it didn't work for the OP, as Deepak Patankar said in his comment, you may want to try a

```
git fetch
```

first. It seems like an easier place to start than special parameters on a pull command.