# Failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/laravel-vue2.git'

Tags: django, heroku

I want to upload my application which uses Django to Heroku. I run `heroku create xxxxx` and `git push heroku` but I get the following error.

> error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/xxxxxxxxx.git'

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114676/git-error-failed-to-push-some-refs-to-remote

Comment: why your selected tag are php , laravel , vue.js while ur question is related to django

Comment: If your git branch is `master`, try `git push heroku master:main`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git error: failed to push some refs to remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114676/git-error-failed-to-push-some-refs-to-remote)