# git corrupted by someone not used to using git

Tags: git, github

I am not sure what this person keeps doing, but I keep getting into situations where my git pull (on master) fails like so

```
(base) Deans-MacBook-Pro:webpieces dean$ git pull
error: cannot update the ref 'refs/remotes/origin/victor/Delete_List_Copy': unable to append to '.git/logs/refs/remotes/origin/victor/Delete_List_Copy': Not a directory
From github.com:deanhiller/webpieces
 ! [new branch]          victor/Delete_List_Copy -> origin/victor/Delete_List_Copy  (unable to update local ref)
```

I run these commands which run just fine

- git clone git@github.com:deanhiller/webpieces.git webpieces3
- git checkout victor/Delete_List_Copy

I am not sure what he does exactly but eventually my git repo has this directory which I keep deleting (and which does not exist via git branch -r neither) ->

```
.git/refs/remotes/origin/victor/
```

I then run

1. rmdir .git/refs/remotes/origin/victor/
2. git pull

git pull fails with the first error in this SO post.  The victor directory is back with a vengeance and I have no idea why.

Next, I try git remote prune origin

This does not help as git pull results in same error.

Over time, each repo seems to become corrupt on just git pull.  I have no idea why this is occurring nor how to fix this repo resulting in yet another git clone to start over :(

Comment: What if you *don't* delete this directory?

Comment: Have you tried `git pull --rebase`? I don't think the repo is corrupted, rather an issue with different versions of git. It could be related to https://stackoverflow.com/a/24114760/15515525

Comment: The golden rule is that you don't mess with stuff inside `.git` by hand unless you know what you are doing. Why do you manually delete that directory?

Answer (score 1):

Your remote is behaving as if "victor" is serially making and deleting branches named `victor` and `victor/whatever`. Say `git pull -p` to get the fetch it runs  to delete any stale refs first, that should prevent this kind of mismatch.

Comment: Based on the prompt, Dean Hiller is using a Mac, probably with the default case-insensitive file system. I'll bet whoever controls the upstream repository has created one branch named `Victor` and one named `victor/Thing`, or perhaps `victor` and `Victor/thing`, and is using Linux or similar and hence has case-sensitive branch behavior.

Comment: I think it's Dean Hiller who controls the upstream repository, and he's manage to shoot himself in the foot because the upstream repo is on GitHub. :-)

Comment: @torek haha well, it can't be both. Perhaps there's somebody named victor with push rights doing the case-sensitive branches you describe?

Comment: Yes—or, given that it's a fork, perhaps the original repo had them all along?

Comment: @torek Yah. Regardless, I think you've got it, I didn't catch the import of the prompt (and OP never showed a capitalized Victor branch). Add that as an answer why don't you? Pretty sure it's the answer.