# git push Error : ![rejected] main ->main (non-fast-forward) error: falied to push some refs to http://github.com/

Tags: git, github

I tried push to github and get this error : How can i fix it ?
error:
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+hint%3A+Updates+were+rejected+because+a+pushed+branch+tip+is+behind+its+remote

Answer (score 2):

I think it's just because your branch on the remote repo (on GitHub) has commits that you don't have locally.

> It's written in the error message (hint:)

What you should try to do is to first get what you have on otn repo with a `git pull` and resolve conflicts (if there are any) to then do the push.

Look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114676/git-error-failed-to-push-some-refs-to-remote) to understand better ;)