# failed to push some refs after moving SSD to new PC

Tags: git, github

Recently I upgraded my PC and have added my old SSD with my git repos over to my new system.

Before I was working on native Ubuntu18, now I'm on Ubuntu20 on Windows Subsystem for Linux 2.

After installing my old SSD and navigating to its new location, I am able to git pull my repo but am unable to push changes with the error `error: failed to push some refs to...` appearring.

I have followed [git error: failed to push some refs to remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114676/git-error-failed-to-push-some-refs-to-remote) without any success.

Note this is only for one of my repos. Other repos on the same SSD can pull, edit files, commit, and push no problem.

Any ideas of how to troubleshoot? I think this maybe an authentication/permissions issue that's repo specific?

Comment: Can you share the full error message?

Comment: The full message is basically `error: failed to push some refs to [repo_ssh_url]`, but replace `[repo_ssh_url]` with the the url of the repo. However, I should note that we recently changed the name of the repo on github, but I also used `git remote set-url origin [new_ssh_url]` accordingly.

Comment: `failed to push some refs to <url>` is the error message emitted *after* each of the *more specific* failures for each failed name. There *must* be such errors; perhaps some software you're using to wrap Git has hidden them from you; if so, avoid such software.

Answer (score 0):

So after painstakingly comparing my repos that do work with the one that does not work, I figured out that I had git-LFS installed on that repo but never used it. For some reason it never threw any errors while on my old system.

After removing git-LFS, I am now able to push again.