# Problem in committing changes to Angular GitHub Page

Tags: angular, github-pages

all,

I face error when I try to commit changes directly to Angular Github Page.

I used the following command:
git push origin gh-pages
However, I see this error warning: "failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Savalan11/angularPage.git'"
How can I address this issue and successfully commit changes to github page?

Many thanks beforehand..

Comment: Please include full error message and relevant git history via something like `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is no log files attached and we can't look into problem properly, here are a few steps you can try to troubleshoot the issue:

1. Make sure that you have committed all of your changes locally before trying to push them to the remote repository.
2. Make sure that you have the correct remote repository set up in your local repository. You can check this by running the command `git remote -v` and seeing if the repository listed is the one you want to push to.
3. Make sure that you have the correct branch checked out locally. The `gh-pages` branch should be checked out before running the `git push` command.
4. If you are still having trouble, it could be that there are conflicts between the version of the code in your local repository and the version that is currently on the `gh-pages` branch. In this case, you will need to resolve the conflicts before you can push your changes. Also, look into similar related topics, for example: [git error: failed to push some refs to remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114676/git-error-failed-to-push-some-refs-to-remote)
5. Finally, if none of the above steps have helped, it's possible that there is a problem with the connection to the remote repository. In this case, you can try again later to see if the issue resolves itself, or you can try pushing to a different branch and then merging the changes into the `gh-pages` branch.

If the problem is not solved yet, it might be helpful to send here the full output with an error.