# How to add modification to a submitted change in Git?

Tags: git, cherry-pick, git-reset

I have pushed a change in Git with a little mistake. How to add some modification in that same changelist? I heard that it's possible using cherrypick. I'm unable to find how.

Comment: "I'm unable to find how." reading documentation maybe or git book? http://git-scm.com/book

Comment: I tried. But unable to understand.

Comment: Maybe start with using git extensions instead of command line. https://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is probably [amend](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorial/rewriting-git-history#!commit-amend) it lets you add your changes to a commit you already made.

The question is have you pushed to a remote or did you just commit? If you only commited ammend is fine but if the commit has been pushed to a remote repository you will have to make a new commit for your changes.

You could [push the amended commit to remote but you shouldn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253055/how-do-i-push-amended-commit-to-the-remote-git-repo)...

Comment: amend is to make changes before pushing I guess. isn't it?

Comment: I think the user is looking for changing a pushed commit; in this case the amend does not work

Comment: @sop That's why I said if it is already pushed you will have to make a new commit. You don't change pushed commits.

Comment: That's what my question is. I heard that there is an option to do it on the lastly pushed change. Are you sure it's not possible?

Comment: You can amend it and push the new commit but that will change the commit history and break it for everyone who already pulled your old commit and did something on that

Comment: See [how-do-i-push-amended-commit-to-the-remote-git-repo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253055/how-do-i-push-amended-commit-to-the-remote-git-repo). It works but is not recommended