# How do I push amended commit to the remote git repo on a specific commit

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-amend

I already edit some files in my repo and push them.
After some other work, I noticed that i keep a line commented.
So, i don't want to create a new commit for it and I want to change it in the previous commit (Not the last one commit).
I think that i can use the commit ID, but i don't know how or maybe Git not tolerating this feature.

Comment: Use `-f` flag with `git push` command

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I push amended commit to the remote git repo?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253055/how-do-i-push-amended-commit-to-the-remote-git-repo)

Answer (score 6):

You can do a rebase in interactive mode:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~10
```

Git will prompt you with a list of commits, with the oldest ones showing up first:

```
...
pick ab89k22 Old commit
pick ml9826x Another old commit
pick xke82ml This is the commit you want to edit
pick aow82md Here is your latest commit
```

Find the commit you want to edit, and change `pick` to `edit`:

```
edit xke82ml This is the commit you want to edit
```

Then save the file and exit.  Git will now begin the rebase and will *stop* at the commit you want to edit, allowing you to make changes.  Once you have finished making those changes, you can type

```
git add path/to/file
```

for each file you modiifed, and then type

```
git rebase --continue
```

to finish the rebase.

Note that in editing this commit on your local branch, you have effectively *rewritten* history.  This means that when you push to the remote, you will have to *force* the branch out, using `--force` in your `git push` command:

```
git push origin master --force
```

Be wary that rewriting the remote history can be dangerous depending on who is also sharing this branch with you.

If you *don't* want to rewrite the remote history, then a safer bet would be to add a new commit to your branch.  You could also remove the commit in question using `git revert`, and then add the changes you want to keep.

Comment: When i execute the "git rebase --continue" after I have finished my change. Git say that "Working tree is dirty" and display my files whith display "needs update"

Comment: You need to add the files you have changed, as you would normally when doing your work.  Not sure if you also need to commit.

Answer (score 4):

**Don't!**

As Tim points out: it's dangerous to rewrite remote history.

Simply accept that you made a mistake (and didn't test your code thoroughly before pushing it), fix your mistake and **make a new commit with the message**

```
amend <COMMIT_HASH_YOU_WANT_TO_FIX>
```

If you're using a half-decent history viewer, it will generate a link out of `<COMMIT_HASH_YOU_WANT_TO_FIX>` so you could easily jump to the errornous commit.