# github code frequency graph scale problem after initial commit

Tags: git, github, graph, charts, frequency

My initial commit of a project is much larger than subsequent commits that I'd like to see reflected in the code frequency graph of github. In my case this is because I've inherited a code base that wasn't already in github. But also consider it is often the case that an initial push of any project might be an order of magnitude greater than regular commits. In beginning a new application, constant pushing of experimental and dev code before the POC (proof of concept) or MVP (minimal viable product) or whatever you want to call it, is a worthless task that pushes worthless code, which then has to be deleted, instead of just not pushed when the first milestone is reached. One could alternatively after reaching that point then go about committing small portions to artificially produce a smaller scaled initial graph. This is rather absurd since we are talking about merely adjusting the scale of the graph so that we limit the maximum y axis value displayed. You know make a slider to adjust. Not rocket science. Any competitors to github or free service offering this feature? I could then see both views. While typing this I have another idea, which would be to adjust the x axis, which would essentially have the same effect since you could eliminate the initial commit. X axis control also lets you avoid the shrinking problem of project begun 2 years ago, and then resumes activity, but scaling make your current commits again look tiny. Give me both and throw in being able to selectively remove commits from the graph for good measure, as long as you're mucking about. That last one nice to have but not essential, although it would do in pinch if easier to implement than the other two.
Is there any git code or command or free project that does this already?

Related to but not a duplicate, I already found
[How to remove old commit from Git/Github graphs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35436590/how-to-remove-old-commit-from-git-github-graphs)

Answer (score 0):

You can use curl to download your commits to a file

```
curl -u username:password \
https://api.github.com/repos/username/repository/commits \
> commit_history.txt
```

Then write some code to scan the file and output dates versus commit count, size or whatever.

Finally load the output from the history parser into a decent plotting package ( excel would do ) and adjust scaling, axis ranges or whatever you need.