# How to fix a git commit --amend on the head of a remote branch?

Tags: git, github, commit, git-amend

I make this git mistake sometimes and its incredibly annoying. I was wondering whether anyone in the community had ideas for what to do when you accidentally do a commit --amend on the head of a remote branch. Right now I end up doing a pull, diffing against my own partial change, and pushing, resulting in a duplicate commit message on the HEAD.

For clarity, I'm asking the best way to fix the following:

1. Pull remote branch (e.g. master)
2. Make change
3. Commit --amend change
4. Try to push, get rejected
5. Curse self and/or gods

Comment: Pretty sure this is a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253055/how-do-i-push-amended-commit-to-the-remote-git-repository#432518). Bad idea unless it's a repo only you and you and a couple of friends are using.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I push amended commit to the remote Git repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253055/how-do-i-push-amended-commit-to-the-remote-git-repository)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
git stash save -u
git pull -f --rebase
git stash apply
```

The second command will update your local brach based on the remote one while preserving the additional commits to your local branch.
Tell us whether it helps.