# How to amend part of files of last commit after push

Tags: git

How can I amend part of files of last commit after push? I don't want ot create a new commit, but it's acceptable to squash a new commit into the previous commit.

Comment: Where's the question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I properly force a Git push?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509543/how-do-i-properly-force-a-git-push)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is **Never ever modify a commit that is already pushed**.

The long answer can you find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253055/how-do-i-push-amended-commit-to-the-remote-git-repository)