# Can't push refs to remote try running pull first to integrate your changes

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I keep getting this error when I try to push to GitHub from VScode.
I've pushed before to that repository following the exact same steps I am following now. Can't find an answer to what is the reason for this error?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You get this `try running pull first to integrate your changes` whenever your local branch and your remote branch are not on the same point, before your changes.

```
remote branch commits : A -> B -> C -> D
local branch commits  : A -> B -> C -> Local_Commits
```

Now clearly, there's a change `D` that you don't have integrated locally. So you need to `rebase`, then push, which will lead to the following.

```
remote branch commits : A -> B -> C -> D
local branch commits  : A -> B -> C -> D -> Local_Commits
```

To solve your issue, do the following

```
git pull --rebase origin branchname
git push origin branchname
```

Comment: yeah good one this deleted all my changes and dopwnloaded stupid old version from github

Answer (score 12):

VS Code will display this message for a bunch of different errors where the remote rejects your commits, not just the issue described.

In my case, I had the error "The object will increase this repository size by 38642606 bytes (the limit is 10485760 bytes)" because I was committing a large file to the repository.

If you are encountering this issue AND it's not because you're out of sync with remote (as per top answer), I suggest actually using the Git CLI, it will show you a more useful error message.

Comment: "I suggest actually using the Git CLI, it will show you a more useful error message." -> thanks, this made me realize my issue: exposing a private email address

Comment: An alternative to using the Git cli app to expose more detailed errors messages is to click on the "Show command output" button of the error popup in Vscode. Like @user224567893, I too had the github private email address exposure error.

Answer (score 10):

One possible reason that you get the "Failed to push some refs" error is that you do not have enough permission to push to the current branch (probably master). You need to ask project maintainers to give you enough permission or you need to push your changes to another branch and make a merge/pull request.

Answer (score 9):

In my case, I used `git push --no-verify`. It worked

Comment: why would you NOT want to verify and sign your commits when you have your config set up to do so?

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes it's not your fault. Don't forget to check https://www.githubstatus.com/ if you're getting completely unexpected errors. This is pretty bad, but at least they're all only yellow and not red

[image]

Comment: Yes, it would be nice if they added a line in the error message suggesting you check your remote repo status since it can also cause that error.

Answer (score 3):

I got a similar issue, try these below cases any one of the below cases might solve your issue:

1. After resolving merge conflicts, it's expecting you to commit your changes:
   `git commit -m "resolved merge conflicts or any other message"`
2. Click on "*git pull from*" option in VSCode and resolve conflicts, if any.
3. `git pull --rebase origin develop`.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this message in my Azure DevOps Repos environment because the server had a branch policy on the master branch that requires pull request approval and I was trying to push to master directly. Even after pull and rebase the same message appears. I don't think VS Code really knows how to interpret this specific error coming back from the server so it gives the generic message. If I try the same push with git directly it shows a remote rejected error that explains the problem. So my answer only applies in this 1 narrow case, but it can definitely cause the same error message to appear when pushing in VS Code.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I got it because (in a personal) project I pushed a commit, and then I added a change and I did a `git commit --amend`.

So I ended up having two commits with the same title but different ids. One on `origin/HEAD` and one in `HEAD -> master`.
In that case if it's on a personal project, i.e. a project that nobody else is pushing commits, it's ok to `push --force`.

Other wise check this post: [How do I push amended commit to the remote Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253055/how-do-i-push-amended-commit-to-the-remote-git-repository)

Answer (score 2):

In my case was because the tests were failing and the package Husky was installed. The package.json had the following config:

```
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged",
      "pre-push": "npm run test"
    }
  }
```

So if it fails "pre-push", it won't allow you to push anything.

Answer (score 2):

Try running `git push origin <branchname>` in the terminal. That will give you more detailed info.

In my case I got this:

`remote: GitLab: Commit message does not follow the pattern '^\[(projectname)-\d{1,6}]\s.*`

So it wasn't an issue with refs or heads at all. Once I fixed the commit message so it follows the required pattern, the error went away and the push went through.

Answer (score 1):

1-) Firstly check the **output** section from VSCode

2-) If there is such a message like this: "This repository is configured for Git LFS but 'git-lfs' was not found on your path. If you no longer wish to use Git LFS, remove this hook by deleting the 'pre-push' file in the hooks directory (set by 'core.hookspath'; usually '.git/hooks')."

3-) You should try installing git lfs from here: https://git-lfs.com/

Answer (score 0):

This issue could be related to local Git hooks, try the following command and it should work :

```
git pull --rebase origin <yourBranchName>
git push origin <yourBranchName>
git push --no-verify
```

Answer (score 0):

it's working for this code and very useful

git push --no-verify

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: this is a late duplicate answer of another answer provided 2 years before it. ZERO VALUE

Answer (score 0):

It may happen if trying to amend an already pushed commit.
If that is the case, you'll need to force push.

However in VSCode UI this may require to use `Push to.. (Force)` in case you have **multiple remotes** (e.g. "origin" and "upstream"):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, saying `` refusing to allow a Personal Access Token to create or update workflow `...` without `workflow` scope `` and the problem lied on the github personal access token was not including `workflow` scope. Just created new token including that scope too and it works like a charm!

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67765064/1369501

Answer (score 0):

Follow these commands and run this on the terminal:

```
git pull --rebase origin branchname
git push origin branchname
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, then saw in the terminal I had some file that was exceeding GitHub's file size limit (100mb). Deleted the git folder and initialized a new repo.

Answer (score -1):

I would advise not to run `git pull` commands unless you know what you are doing. It downloads old version from your repository and overwrites any work you've done on your computer without asking. In fact, some people have had it overwrite their entire file system with the repo, so be careful.

So if you run into this issue, make sure you have your folder opened in VSCode.

Try pressing the blue button two times like you normally do; `Publish branch` will fail showing an error message, press `Open Git Log` in the error window.

In the git log you have to scroll up a bit until you see something like `git push -u origin main`. The different thing might be that `origin` might be called something different.

Copy the command. Then go to `terminal` tab, paste the command and add `--force` to it, like this:  `git push --force -u origin main`.

Pressing enter to execute it will upload all new changes into your github repository, **overwriting everything in it**. If somebody else works on the same repo, it might delete their work by replacing it with your outdated version, but at that stage you probably know git enough to not need this thread.

After those steps, next time you can just use the blue `Commit` -> `Publish branch` buttons in VSCode and it will work.

Comment: how can it possibly overwrite the entire filesystem?  second you have a reflog you can restore from.   `git push --force -u origin main` is HORRIBLE advice to blindly do. YOU SHOULD NOT BE FORCE PUSHING MAIN UNLESS YOU KNOW DAMN WELL WHAT YOU ARE DOING and anyone asking this question by definition does not.

Comment: @UpAndAdam simple, imagine you are a newbie and just made a simple project on D drive root, and VSCode doesn't want to upload it on github, instead it tells you "pull from the repo", whatever that means, they couldn't call it downloading and overwriting existing files, they had to call it "pull" so that you have to read documentation to know what it means, so a newbie, he doesn't read documentation, he press the giant friendly blue VSCode button, surely VSCode devs know better, bam, the entire D drive is gone and replaced with the github repo

Comment: @UpAndAdam here is another case, you open a random file in D drive root, VSCode sets it as your project folder, then you create a new folder somewhere else and start working with it, try to upload on github, same thing, this time you aren't a newbie just didn't notice your project folder is different. Those are real by the way, https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/px5glu/so_funny_story_i_tried_learning_git_ended_up/ https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/lo413x/novice_mistake_deleted_all_my_hobby_projectstests/ https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/32405

Comment: pull is a merge, a merge wouldnt delete unless you had common files that were deleted remotely that had existed previously AND you didnt make changes locally causing a conflict.  secondly you would have a sea of uncomitted changes that would block the merge.  microsoft post reeks of a troll and was not a merge or a pull it was seperate stupidity with no supporting evidence.

Comment: use cases you describe are so absurd and incomplete they are meritless. There is no such thing as "try to upload on github"  there is git push which would require a git init and commit first, and there is fetch and merge and pull.  lastly you said ENTIRE FILESYSTEM. that literally will not happen.

Comment: you should pull --rebase in your situation don't tell people to blindly force push. that is the worst GIT advice I have ever heard, as is your entire answer.  I literally had to help an entire department cleanup the result of an idiot having done that who lost everyone's work on every branch becuase he did `git push --force` good thing i had a good backup mirror that hadn't fetched his changes.
you should fetch before you push, and either merge or rebase your changes accordingly.  unless you are dealing with an exceptional case where someone ELSE force pushed, you shouldnt be force pushing.

Comment: " It downloads old version from your repository " NO pull fetches the latest version from your remote and merges or rebases it into your current branch depending on your config. You dont even understand how things work and are trying to tell people what to do.

Comment: @UpAndAdam pull will not merge when push doesn't work. Because the reason push doesn't work in the question is because it doesn't realize that local files are new version of github files, and it will just overwrite them when using pull. By old version I mean you probably added new stuff to your local project that you haven't uploaded to github and pull will delete all of that new stuff. And "git init and commit first" are two shiny blue buttons in vscode, one appears after you press the other, a newbie will happily press them just because of how big and blue they are

Comment: again not a true statement.  you have no idea whether or not pull will merge or not from that error message alone.  You are making grand generalizations off of an absurd special case you ran into.  what you have never explained is how 'clicking two buttons' to git init is going to hook the project up to some OTHER project on github that has different content than this project. among many other things.. do you understand how git actually works? You are making a very bold assumption as to the reason push doesnt work when there are many reasons push would fail legitimately that you dont consider

Comment: @UpAndAdam it isn't a special case. It is extremely easy to reproduce. Simply download github repo as ZIP, unpack and open the folder in vscode, then connect folder to the repo. Or just start the project over in a new folder. You will have the same issue. And it won't hook your poject to some other repo - it will hook it to that same repo. However you work on your project  locally, then try to upload on github, follow someones advice from this thread, pull from github, all your new local work will be gone and overwritten by outdated github repo without confirmation.

Comment: "download github repo as zip" you failed at step one.. that's not you how you work with git, you clone.  you dont have a proper clone. that said I will entertain that by trying it out elsewhere.  But again if you had pulled immediately after 'downloading' and bringing into your project you also wouldnt have had this problem.  So i downloaded a zip extracted and opened a project from it.  i clicked initialize repo... it says that every file is a change.... this is an instant clue that you screwed up and you need to stop.  This is 100% user error. I commit my 'changes' on main.

Comment: Commit fails because nothing is setup properly, the amount of problems in the git commit log window is clear indication we are FUBAR.  also "no remotes found in git config file" are among the many errors telling you you did this wrong.  If you can't commit you can't pull... i edited gitconfig to put my name and email, now it commits and offers publish branch. can't go forward I'm blocked from github at work can only go to GHE and this plugin is not setup for that. if you had made a commit, it's in your reflog and you can restore it.  but remote repo isnt even configured yet so i cant pull.

Comment: Moral of story is that if you are working with git you should follow basic instructions and start by a git clone.  Your example is beyond trite and stupid. If you performed any sanity check at all before starting to work you wouldnt have caused any of this.