# How to resolve "refusing to allow an OAuth App to create or update workflow" on git push

Tags: git, github, github-actions

Getting

> refusing to allow an OAuth App to create or update workflow `.github/workflows/cd.yml` without `workflow` scope"

on `git push`. How to grant `workflow` scope?

Comment: How did you create the token you're using to push?  How did you create the OAuth app?  Did the OAuth app request the `workflow` scope when requesting scopes for the token?  We need a lot more details about what's going on and how it was set up to be able to give you a useful answer.

Comment: @bk2204 I used https github clone.

Answer (score 307):

I've literally just come across this problem when trying to use IntelliJ to push to a branch that contains a GitHub Action workflow (`YAML` file in .github/workflows). I didn't find existing resources on the Internet very helpful, so I hope this will help you fix it too.

TL;DR: Update your Personal Access Token with the `workflow` scope enabled in GitHub, or create a new one, and configure your application to use that.

Background: third-party tools with GitHub integrations like IntelliJ, Visual Studio Code, Github Desktop, etc use tokens to connect to your GitHub account so they can pull/push, etc on your behalf. In the case of IntelliJ, their instructions only say to include the `repo`, the `gist`, and the `read:org` scopes. But you need the `workflow` scope to modify GitHub Actions.

Here's how to fix it:

1. In your Github account, go to **Settings** (in your avatar dropdown in the top right-hand corner)
2. Go to **Developer Settings** > **Personal Access Tokens**
3. If your token is listed, update it to include the `workflow` scope:

   - Click on the token name.
   - Select `workflow` scope and save.
   - If the app you use won't re-fetch permissions for your token automatically, you may have to create a new one (step 4 below).
   - Click on **Update Token** to save the change. DONE!
4. If there's no token listed there, generate a new one:

   - Click on **Generate Token**.
   - Select the scopes you need, including `workflow`.
   - Read the information carefully, then click OK to continue.
   - Copy the new token that Github shows you.
   - Apply the new token to your application. For example, for the Intellij IDE, go to **Settings** > **Version Control** > **GitHub**, remove the existing integration and re-add it, pasting in the new token.

Comment: Can someone explain why this happens?

Comment: You can also edit current Personal Access Token to change its scope by including `workflow` to it. This is exactly what I just did to overcome the issue.

Comment: @Xanlantos I think it's because the Workflow thing didn't exist when you originally created the token

Comment: @gondadarian. Yes! Thank you. Updating existing user personal access token and adding `workflow` to it was the most seamless and easiest way to solve this problem. Thanks so much for sharing that !

Comment: I can't find the "workflow" box to tick :(

Comment: "You will need to recreate your application's integration with Github using the new token for the change to take effect." How does one do this?

Comment: It seems unnecessary to regenerate the token. It can save some headaches.

Comment: People still struggling: make sure to update 'Tokens (classic)' not the 'fine-grained tokens (beta)'. Hope you read this!

Comment: At the date of Sept. 2023 I find no personal access token anywhere. Is it hidden somewhere or did GitHub remove that feature?

Answer (score 68):

Running macOS. I am pushing my `.yml` workflow file from my text editor.

1. Go to [github personal access tokens settings](https://github.com/settings/tokens) and generate a new token. Make sure you select both repo and workflow access scope.

[image: 2]

2. Go to Keychain Access app on Mac, and search for github. I found an entry (shown below) named `github.com`, of `Internet password` kind, which was **previously filled with a seemingly random token**. Replace the password entry with the generated token (the one begins with `ghp_`) from step 1.

[image: 3]

Comment: where should the password be entered?

Comment: @toan double click an entry, a window pops up, then click "show password" in the window to edit it

Answer (score 57):

For Windows 10: Go to Settings -> Credentials Manager -> Windows Credentials -> Remove github.com credentials -> git pull/push your github project from git-bash console -> Reconnect GitHub Account in your IDE/Source control.
You don't need create Personal Access Token with "workflow", you don';t need create secret GITHUB_TOKEN (it creates auto and can't created manual)

Comment: For me, it was deleting all github related credentials and logout and back in in the github desktop app. But closest answer by far!

Comment: I encountered this after adding a custom action for firebase hosting to my repository. For me on windows.   I had installed git via git desktop; but was pushing both from the command line and from vscode.   Going to the github desktop client and re-logging in was enough.

Answer (score 29):

This issue also happens simply because your current token is not allowed to work with workflow on Github.
Do the following steps to fix

For people using Android Studio on MacOS:

1. Delete your current token (Preferences -> Version Control -> GitHub):
   [image]

remember to hit the "Ok" button.

2. Try to push/pull again from Android Studio, an popup now will appear.
   [image]
3. Hit Use Token... button, another popup will appear.
   [image]
4. Click on Generate, you will be sent to GitHub website to generate a new token. Remember to select the workflow permission.
   [image]
5. Click generate Button to get a new token and paste it to Android Studio in step 3. It's all set now.

Answer (score 19):

#### On Windows 10 Here is step by step how I was able to fix the issue

**I've included lots of screenshots `cause this was way harder to resolve then it should have been.**

In hind sight, what @CSRedRat said is right but as I was having the problem I couldn't understand that because the answer was so terse.

Ultimately what led me to the solution was [this article](https://jessehouwing.net/cannot-push-to-github-without-workflow-scope/) which makes the situation more clear.

Here's the deal. While you *can* work around this issue using the GitHub Developer Settings Menu to generate a new token and then pasting that into the Windows Credential Manager, you **shouldn't** because eventually that token will expire and then you will be having this issue again since nothing will know how to refresh the token since you set it manually.

**Instead**, this token privs issue needs fixed via Git for Windows. So the deal is the "old" Git Credential Manager for Windows didn't ask for privs to create or update workflows but now you need them.  The good news is there is a new version our called Git [Credential Manager Core](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core) and it does ask for these privs and more.

The new credential manager ships with Git 2.28 and later, but isn't enabled by default. If you already have Git for Window of this version or later installed then you already have the software even.  In my case I had version 2.30.2 so I already had the new software.

[image]

But it was still using my old Git for Windows credentials which don't carry the privs needed. That may be your case as well or if you don't have a version older 2.28 then you need to first install a newer version.  Either way, once you have a new enough version of Git for Windows on your machine the next step is to remove the old credentials by typing "windows credential manager" in the windows search box.

[image]

Then find each git credential, click on it and click the remove button.

[image]

Now next time you try to access your get account from `git bash` Visual Studio or whatever git client you use, you will be prompted for new credentials because the old ones are gone. Click the `Sign in with your browser` button in the dialog below:

[image]

Then you will see a web page like this one below, and if you expand the workflow drop down you will see it is asking for the privs you need this time. Then click `Authorize` button.

[image]

Once you do that, you will see a page like this for providing your github password:

[image]

Now you have a new credential in your windows credential manager that has the privs you need and your operation that use to fail will now succeed. Yea!

Comment: Not work for Sourcetree 3.3.4 Windows 11 22H2.

Answer (score 16):

In my case, I had stale GitHub credentials in macOS Keychain. I was modifying a workflows file and pushing the changes from the command line, hence I didn't think of checking the Keychain at all. The [Updating credentials from the macOS Keychain](https://docs.github.com/en/github/using-git/updating-credentials-from-the-macos-keychain) explained how to use `git credential-osxkeychain` to erase the Keychain:

```
$ git credential-osxkeychain erase
host=github.com
protocol=https
> [Press Return]
```

I then had to enter my username and password again. This time I generated a new personal access token and used that token for the password. Then I could finally push the workflows changes.

Answer (score 12):

This error occurs when your local environment is configured using the [github cli](https://cli.github.com/). It's not immediately clear what's needed to update the permissions. In the case of the CLI, though, you can run the below command to enable it and then proceed forward.

`gh auth login --scopes workflow`

Comment: I received this error when I was trying to push a local repo (containing workflows) to a new, bare GitHub repo. This solution fixed it for me.

Comment: Nice find, thanks! That's the way to fix the issue if you used the `gh auth login` command (Github CLI) to setup your local git environment.

Answer (score 9):

1. Find your token, should be here https://github.com/settings/tokens
2. Grant `workflow` as showing below
   [image]

Answer (score 6):

Fixed this by using the `Desktop Github App` for pushing my changes (it seems to have full permissions vs. the limited scope of vs code).

After getting that one commit with the modified workflow file pushed through, I was able to make push commits normally again in `vs code`.

Comment: This worked for me. Is there a way to modify the permissions for vs code?

Answer (score 4):

You also can change from using https to using SSH.

1. Create your SSH key, you can follow the [docs](https://docs.github.com/es/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent#generating-a-new-ssh-key).
2. Change your remote from https to SSH, also you can follow the [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/managing-remote-repositories#switching-remote-urls-from-https-to-ssh).

Answer (score 4):

I run into the same issue after pushing my initial commit for an *nbdev* project. This did the the trick for me:

1. deleting all `.yaml` files under `.github/workflows`
2. `git add .`, `git commit -m "CommitMessage"` and `git push`
3. adding the `.yaml` files directly on GitHub (under *Actions* tab and then *New workflow*
4. `git pull`

*Then you can keep on working on your local repo and should be able to push your changes to Github without any error messages.*

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me on GitKraken. I simply disconnected and reconnected GitHub from GitKraken and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

If you push to a repo and see:

> (refusing to allow a Personal Access Token to create or update workflow `.github/workflows/docker_build_push.yml` without `workflow` scope)

It means the GitHub Personal Access Token (PAT) you're using doesn't have 'Workflows' permissions.

## To fix

1. Go here: https://github.com/settings/tokens
2. Create a new Personal Access Token (PAT) and be sure to check the 'workflows' box
3. Copy the resulting PAT to clipboard
4. Delete or revoke any existing PAT(s) (this is done at the same GitHub link)
5. Since the existing PAT was revoked/deleted, next time you push/pull from a private repo you'll be prompted for a github username (your actual github username or email will work) and a password (paste the PAT into the password field).

That's it! It should push and the error should be gone now.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue with CLion 2020.2.3 while attempting to push a change to .\github\workflows\build.yml. CLion appears to use the "JetBrains IDE Integration" token (GitHub Settings -> Applications -> Authorized OAuth Apps) which does not include the "workflow" scope. There does not appear to be a way to change the scope of this token.

I created a new Personal Access Token with the correct permissions (GitHub Settings -> Developer settings -> Personal access tokens -> Generate new token), but I was unable to configure CLion to use it.

Ultimately I was able to push the commit using GitHub Desktop instead.

Comment: I had the same issue with RubyMine. Despite creating a new token with the workflow scope it behaved as if it wasn't granted the scope. I eventually got it to work by rebooting, though I now suspect simply restarting RubyMine would have worked as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had to upgrade my [Git For Windows](https://gitforwindows.org/) to version 2.29.2.2. That allowed the git command line to sign in through the browser, which GitHub now requires.

I did this after trying a Windows Credential Manager reset and regenerating my Personal Access Token, which didn't resolve it. But it did cause GitHub to send me an email like this:

> [GitHub] Action required - Password authentication in Git for Windows is no longer supported
>
> We have detected that you recently attempted to authenticate to GitHub using an older version of Git for Windows. GitHub has changed how users authenticate when using Git for Windows, and now requires the use of a web browser to authenticate to GitHub. To be able to login via web browser, users need to update to the latest version of Git for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I followed [this article](https://jessehouwing.net/cannot-push-to-github-without-workflow-scope/) to install [Git Credential Manager Core](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager) to handle this automatically - and it works well for me (macOS):

Using homebrew:

```
brew tap microsoft/git
brew install --cask git-credential-manager-core
```

Comment: This worked for me without a hitch.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me on PHPStorm. I was trying to use the IDE to commit and push my alterations, so when i got the error, i tried to push with command line on IDE console and i got it.

Answer (score 0):

For IntelliJ IDE users, follow these simple steps:

1. Go to Files > Settings > Version Control > Github and remove the Github account by clicking on the account and then on the '-' button.
2. Then Sign in to Github.com in your default browser & then click on
   the '+' button on the same IDE window we opened in step 1. Then
   select 'Login with token'.
3. Click on the Generate Button.
4. This will open a GitHub page in your browser with all the permission
   prefilled. All you have to do is click on 'Generate Token' at the
   bottom of the page. Then use that token to fill it in the IDE pop-up
   window.
5. Close the settings window & push your code again. This always works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have one personal GitHub account (Spragucm) and two non-enterprise GitHub organizations (HoverDroids and tCubedStudios).

GitKraken was seeing repos for Spragucm and HoverDroids but not tCubedStudios.

HoverDroids Third-party application access policy was:

[image]

tCubedStudios Third-party application access policy was:

[image]

Notice tCubedStudios didn't list GitKraken and there is no option in the organization to manually add the application.

Signing in/out of GitKraken did not allow me to select and approve another organization, nor did uninstalling/re-installing.

***The Solution:***

1. Open Applications in my personal account (Spragucm)

[image]

2. Select GitKraken settings and click the grant button for the organization (clearly a bad photoshop job in my image, but that's where the button was)

[image]

3. Go to the tCubedStudios Third-party application access policy and verify it now shows GitKraken and GitKraken Services

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It may be unexpected but, in my particular case this error was caused by a custom ~/.netrc file I created for GitHub (private Golang packages installation)

You can go there and check if you have one.

```
machine github.com login {username} password {github_token}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by simply deleting the file `<my-project>\.github\workflows\pre-release-build.yml` and then commiting and pushing

I faced this issue while trying to push a brand new repo. I was surrised to see this as it was brand new but then I realised my `.github` was copied from another hence it needed to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Issue can be solved without PAT token by cloning repository with SSH key.

Comment: this is not a solution, but a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem in VS Code after configuring the hosting of my site with Firebase and giving it permission to perform updates directly from my github repos.

Evidently this configuration changed some settings of github itself.

**To solve it, I simply logged out of the account and logged back in to VS Code.**