# Github Actions error on push to Digital Ocean - refusing to allow an OAuth App to create or update workflow

Tags: yaml, digital-ocean, github-actions, continuous-deployment

I am trying to set up a Node app to deploy to Digital Ocean after pushing to a Github repo. I am using Github actions and have followed [this tutorial](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-deploy-your-application-to-digital-ocean-using-github-actions-and-save-up-on-ci-cd-costs-74b7315facc2) but have hit a snag at step 5. I get the following error when I try to push to the repo.

```
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (refusing to allow an OAuth App to create or update workflow `.github/workflows/main.yaml` without `workflow` scope)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/IT-ACA/hello-node-do.git'
```

I have tried everything I can find, including [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64059610/how-to-resolve-refusing-to-allow-an-oauth-app-to-create-or-update-workflow-on), but nothing works. I have a `.yaml` file in my project, which I can't see anything immediately wrong with, that currently looks like this.

```
name: CI

# Controls when the workflow will run
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the master branch
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "build"
  build:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
      # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
      name: Deploy NodeJS App
      uses: jjst/action-digitalocean-deploy-app@v2 
      with:
        token: ${{ secrets.GH_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
        host: ${{ secrets.SSH_HOST }}
        key: ${{ secrets.SSH_KEY }}
        username: ${{ secrets.SSH_USER }}
        script: | 
          cd hello-node-do
          git clone https://github.com/IT-ACA/hello-node-do.git
          echo 'Deploy successful to Digital Ocean..'
```

Note that I have a different value for `uses` in the yaml code above which comes from [this page](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/digital-ocean-deploy-app) and is what I began my DigitalOcean deployment journey with. But, I have also tried the one from the tutorial linked above without any luck.

I think the secrets are all correctly in place and that I have done everything necessary on the DigitalOcean side but it still throws this error. This is the very first time I have tried implementing a CD/CI pipeline and I have spent hours troubleshooting it now. Running out of ideas and would appreciate any help getting over this frustrating hurdle. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I"m not sure I understand what you're trying to do, but why don't you use [checkout](https://github.com/actions/checkout) do get your repo?

Comment: I just searched for other people using that action, and [here](https://github.com/mota/ifconfig.cloud/blob/ccbb377332fb8ba7d63ac430c29a668b3b09d2dc/.github/workflows/ifconfig.yaml) is a workflow that seems to work (and uses checkout).