# How to use Personal Access Token for Github-CD?

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml, github-actions

I have created a yml file for CD workflow and when I was trying to push it is giving me error
"`refusing to allow a Personal Access Token to create or update workflow` .github/workflows/backend-cd.yml`without`workflow `scope`"

This is my backend-cd.yml file:

```
name: CD - Deploy Backend

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
    paths:
      - backend/**

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      repo-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      run:
        working-directory: ./backend
    services:
      postgres:
        image: postgres:14.5
        env:
          POSTGRES_USER: postgres
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 123456789
          POSTGRES_DB: customer
        ports:
          - "5433:5432"
        options:
          --health-cmd pg_isready
          --health-interval 10s
          --health-timeout 5s
          --health-retries 5
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          distributions: "corretto"
          java-version: "17"
          cache: "maven"
      - name: Login to Docker Hub
        uses: docker/login-action@v2
        with:
          username: ${{secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME}}
          password: ${{secrets.DOCKERHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN}}
      - name: Set build number
        id: build-number
        run: echo "BUILD_NUMBER=$(date '+%d.%m.%Y.%H.%M.%S')" >> GITHUB_OUTPUT
      - name: Build Package Push with Maven
        run: mvn -ntp -B verify -D docker.image.tag=${{steps.build-number.outputs.BUILD_NUMBER}} jib:build
      - name: Update Dockerrun.aws.json api image tag with new build number
        run: |
          echo "Dockerrun.aws.json before updating tag"
          cat Dockerrun.aws.json
          sed -i -E 's_(ahmadmujtaba200210/fullstack:)([^"]*)_\1'${{ steps.build-number.outputs.BUILD_NUMBER }}'_' Dockerrun.aws.json
          echo "Dockerrun.aws.json after updating tag"
          cat Dockerrun.aws.json
      - name: Deploy to Elastic Beanstalk
        uses: einaregilsson/beanstalk-deploy@v21
        with:
          aws_access_key: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws_secret_key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          application_name: ${{ secrets.EB_APPLICATION_NAME }}
          environment_name: ${{ secrets.EB_ENV_NAME }}
          version_label: ${{ steps.build-number.outputs.BUILD_NUMBER }}
          version_description: ${{github.SHA}}
          region: ${{ secrets.EB_REGION }}
          deployment_package: backend/Dockerrun.aws.json
      - name: Commit and push Dockerrun.aws.json

        run: |
          git config user.name github-actions
          git config user.email github-actions@github.com
          git add .
          git commit -m "Update Dockerrun.aws.json docker image with new tag ${{ steps.build-number.outputs.BUILD_NUMBER }}" .
          git push
```

I have created a new PAT with all the permissions.
here is a copy-paste description of permissions from the GitHub personal access token.

> Read and Write access to actions, actions variables, administration, code, codespaces, codespaces lifecycle admin, codespaces secrets, commit statuses, dependabot secrets, deployments, discussions, environments, issues, merge queues, pages, pull requests, repository advisories, repository hooks, secret scanning alerts, secrets, security events, and workflows

I have tried the following things:

1. I have tried as mentioned on the official documentation of GitHub. [GITHUB_TOKEN](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication)
2. I have also added the token to the user.password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend deleting all your existing PATs and then creating a new one with full permissions. After that, remove the old PAT from your local Mac. When you see the 'you are not authenticated' prompt, just input the new PAT.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the token in use and associated with your github account does not have the permission to update the github workflows.

Add the workflow permission to the token you are using with your github account.

[Some pretty good answers on here to help adding the permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64059610/how-to-resolve-refusing-to-allow-an-oauth-app-to-create-or-update-workflow-on).