# Can't push refs to remote. Try running 'Pull' first to integrate your changes

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

I want to push my project to git hub.

I use VSCode editor when i upload my project to github.

I got this type of error

[image]

Comment: what happens if you `pull`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't push refs to remote try running pull first to integrate your changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59790948/cant-push-refs-to-remote-try-running-pull-first-to-integrate-your-changes)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your local repo is not in sync with remote repo. Try-

```
git add .
git commit {"Your message"}
git pull
git push
```